# Overriding variables of Bootstrap-Sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I would like to override the default variables of the bootstrap-sass package.

My core sass file looks like this:

```
@import "../../vendor/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
@import "_variables.scss";
```

My _variables.scss looks like this:

```
$navbar-default-bg: #fff;
```

The default variable of the package looks this way:

```
$navbar-default-bg:                #f8f8f8 !default;
```

When I put something like:

```
.navbar-default {background-color: #fff}
```

in my _variables.scss it will be compiled.

Any suggestions why the default variables aren't overriden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I need to override the variables before importing the bootstrap-sass package.

So the result should look like this:

```
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "../../vendor/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
```